# Inline-block elements are ignoring padding

Tags: css

I have some divs that I wanted to appear side by side, and i wanted them to look like buttons, so i added a background and padding. But I see that for some reason the top padding of the first div is not appearing.

(In my browser the bottom padding was missing from the last one too, but this doesn't appear in the code example.)

I can't figure out why this is, who can offer a solution?

```css
div.i-see-also-link
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color:blanchedalmond;
    height:10px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.i-section-heading {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.i-page-title, h1, h3, h4, .i-section-heading, .i-see-also-sub-heading {
    margin-bottom: -.3em;
}
.i-section-heading {
    clear: both;
}
.i-page-title, h1, h2, h3, h4, .i-section-heading, .i-see-also-sub-heading {
    color: #222;
}
h2, .i-section-heading {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

div {
    display: block;
}
body {
    color: #222;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI',Segoe,'Segoe WP','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.i-section-content > :first-child, .i-description-content > :first-child, .i-returns-content > :first-child, .i-description > :first-child, .i-section-content .i-first-child, .i-description-content .i-first-child, .i-returns-content .i-first-child, .i-description .i-first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
div.i-see-also-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="i-section-heading" id="i-seealso-section-heading"><span class="i-section-heading-icon"><!-- --></span><span class="i-section-heading-text">See Also</span></div><div id="i-seealso-section-content" class="i-section-content" style="display: block;"><div class="i-see-also-link">
<a href="A1R_pMonthlyDebitProcess.html">Monthly</a></div>
<div class="i-see-also-link">
<a href="A1R_fBillingUtility.html">Daily</a></div>
<div class="i-see-also-link">
<a href="A1R_fBillingUtilityFilters.html">Annually</a></div>
<!--DXMETADATA end-->
</div><div id="i-footer-content" class="i-footer-content">
                <!--DXMETADATA start type="Scrap" condition="communityenabled" name="_COMMUNITY_FOOTER" --><!--DXMETADATA end -->
<!--DXMETADATA start type="Variable" name="CopyrightNotice" format="<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><hr style=""height: 1px"" /><p>%%variable%%</p>" --><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><hr style="height: 1px"><p>bla bla bla</p><!--DXMETADATA end -->
<!--DXMETADATA start type="Variable" name="FeedbackLink" format="" --><p>For more information visit theKnowledge Center</p><!--DXMETADATA end-->
            </div>
```

Comment: check carefully your CSS --> `.i-section-content > :first-child` you are setting padding-top:0 here .. specificity issue ... you can add !important to padding-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the `padding-top` doesn't appear is because it's reset by the following rule:

```
.i-section-content > :first-child, .i-description-content > :first-child,
.i-returns-content > :first-child, .i-description > :first-child,
.i-section-content .i-first-child, .i-description-content .i-first-child,
.i-returns-content .i-first-child, .i-description .i-first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

You'll have to override that rule by using a higher priority selector or `!important`.

**Snippet:**

```css
div.i-see-also-link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px!important;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

body {
  color: #222;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Segoe, 'Segoe WP', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.i-section-content> :first-child,
.i-description-content> :first-child,
.i-returns-content> :first-child,
.i-description> :first-child,
.i-section-content .i-first-child,
.i-description-content .i-first-child,
.i-returns-content .i-first-child,
.i-description .i-first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="i-seealso-section-content" class="i-section-content" style="display: block;">
  <div class="i-see-also-link">
    <a href="A1R_pMonthlyDebitProcess.html">Monthly</a></div>
  <div class="i-see-also-link">
    <a href="A1R_fBillingUtility.html">Daily</a></div>
  <div class="i-see-also-link">
    <a href="A1R_fBillingUtilityFilters.html">Annually</a></div>
</div>
```